# Plugin migration quandary

Tags: plugin-development, migration

When exactly are migrations run?  I wrote a migration that runs and does its job properly if I run it via the command line: `yiic migrate up Seomatic` but despite the version number and schema number being bumped, Craft doesn’t run the migration automatically`

Instead, my code dies because of a column that doesn’t exist in the db.  Shouldn't the migration be found and run before my plugin's code is?

Here's the version numbers returned by my plugin:

```
public function getVersion()
{
    return '1.0.5';
}

public function getSchemaVersion()
{
    return '1.0.1';
}
```

The previous installed version was '1.0.4' and '1.0.0', respectively.  Shouldn't this be enough for Craft to find and run the migration?

The migration is named:

```
m151225_000000_seomatic_addHumansField.php
```

...with a class of the same name, and again, it's found and runs properly if manually run it via `yiic` -- what am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

Actually, everything was working fine with the migration.  The issue was that I had code inside of a Twig extension and inside of a rendering hook that was being executed before the migration tried to take place.

I wrapped it in `if (!craft()->request->isCpRequest())` to only do its thing when it's a non-CP request (which is how it probably should have been anyway), and all is well.